# Select rows from a data.table using pattern match

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a string column of the following type

```
dt <- as.data.table(c("IT", "IT01", "IT02", "ITAA"))
```

and I would like to select only the rows that contain exactly two alphabetic characters followed by two numbers. So I would like to filter "IT01" and "IT02" from the table above. I tried:

```
dt <- dt[V1 %like% "[:alpha:]{2}[:digit:]{2}"]
```

but it does not select any rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use double square brackets: `dt[V1 %like% "^[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}$", ]`

Comment: That works, thanks! What's the meaning of the double square bracket? I guess you could put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

We need double square brackets:

```
dt[V1 %like% "^[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}$", ]
```